# Store data in virtuoso triple store using Jena API

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology, virtuoso, rdfs

**WHAT:** I have an ontology and a dataset in CSV format. I want to store this  data (in triple format) in virtuoso triple store, so that I can use it in my application. It might be the case that I need to reason over the stored data.

**APPROACH:**

- Read csv file and convert this into triple format with jena API
- Use SPARQL update to push this data into the virtuoso triple store. Update queries made should be done using the vocabulary of ontology already created.

**QUESTIONS:** With respect to the above approach, I have following questions

- 1. Do I need to store my ontology in virtuoso server also? If yes, should I store the ontology in virtuoso first and then populate it with data (triples).
- 2. If I do not need to store the ontology in virtuoso then how can I reason over the stored data (triples)?
- 3. Do I need to store both ontology and data separately in virtuoso?

I have asked related question before this found at [link](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/31641/use-an-ontology-to-store-csv-data-into-rdf-form), but at that time I populated my ontology with data. I did not use any triple store as the data was too small.

Comment: answer below aside, this is not a programming question, which is the focus of Stack Overflow. RDF/Linked Data questions have a strong audience [here](http://answers.semanticweb.com/), and Virtuoso has a [Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users) and a dedicated [Support forum](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php). There doesn't appear to be anything about Jena nor SPARQL in your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making life harder than it needs to be.

1. [Tell Virtuoso to link the CSV file in as a remote table](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtTipsAndTricksAttachCSVFiles).
2. [Tell Virtuoso to expose RDF Views of the linked CSV table](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRdb2RDFViewsGeneration).

But you can continue as you had planned...

I would recommend that you load the Ontology into one named graph, and load the instance data into a distinct named graph.  It doesn't matter what order you load these into Virtuoso -- RDF isn't like SQL, where you have to define a table or group of tables, and then populate it/them.